# How to generate an MDX query automatically using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdx

I have a table named `calculation` looks like that

```
idPnl        id         operator 

12           13         *
12           14         *
12           15         *

20           1          -
20           2          -

13           21         /
13           20         /
```

I am looking to generate `mdx query` automatically  using script `c#` and write it in a text file :

Example the script will generate  :

```
    Scope (
            {[Dim PNL].[PNL].&[12]}
            ,[Measures].members
    );       
    this = aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[13],[Measures].currentmember)
    * aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[14],[Measures].currentmember)
    *aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[15],[Measures].currentmember);       

    End Scope; 
Scope (
            {[Dim PNL].[PNL].&[20]}
            ,[Measures].members
    );       
    this = aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[1],[Measures].currentmember)
    - aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[2],[Measures].currentmember);       

    End Scope;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you write custom method after loading data from database?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty How can I do it ? could you post a simple example that could be a start point please .

Comment: In C#, I would use LINQ to SQL to a `select` the basic strings like `aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].&[13],[Measures].currentmember)` from `13`, then grouping by idPnl to generate the rest.